# Understanding simulation termination

Tags: python, termination

This is a part of simulation which describes program termination. Could someone please  help me understand how this part of the simulation work i am completely lost. The code is as below:

```
while time_elapsed < end_time :
    event=birth () +death () +infection()
    choice=random.random()*event
    choice -= birth()
    time_elapsed += random.expovariate(event)

    if choice < 0 :
        do_birth()
        continue
    choice -= death()
    if choice < 0:
        do_death()
        continue
```

Comment: **how this part of the simulation work**, it works the way it should work. what's your question exactly?

Comment: `birth()` sounds like bad naming of a function. I guess it's some sort of base chance for the entity? I would've expected `get_birth_chance()` or something like that, now it seems it creates something.

Answer (score 0):

I've rearranged it to hopefully make it more obvious what is happening:

```
# at each time-step until sim ends
while time_elapsed < end_time :

    #
    # decide which random event will occur
    #

    # cumulative probability = (chance of birth) + (chance of death) + (chance of infection)
    event = birth() + death() + infection()
    # choose a value in [0..cum_prob)
    choice = random.random() * event

    # interpret the value:
    # if 0 <= value < (chance of birth)  =>  birth
    # if (chance of birth) <= value < (chance of birth) + (chance of death)   => death
    # if (chance of birth) + (chance of death) <= value < (chance of birth) + (chance of death) + (chance of infection)   => infection

    choice -= birth()
    if choice < 0 :
        do_birth()
        continue

    choice -= death()
    if choice < 0:
        do_death()
        continue

    # "what to do in case of infection" is missing;
    # I assume you chopped it off while cut-and-pasting.

    # forward to next time-step;
    #   this uses an exponential step-size, giving
    #   a normal distribution of event intervals
    #   rather than a uniform step size
    time_elapsed += random.expovariate(event)
```

I would write it a bit differently:

```
while now < stop_at:
    birth_point =               prob_birth()
    death_point = birth_point + prob_death()
    all_events  = death_point + prob_infection()

    event = random.random() * all_events

    if event < birth_point:
        do_birth()
    elif event < death_point:
        do_death()
    else:
        do_infection()

    now += random.expovariate(all_events)
```